# Grappling gun does not become a child of my player when picking it up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I followed a tutorial on Youtube and it was from a man named *Dani*. I also followed another one from someone called *Dave / GameDevelopment* on how to pick up objects in Unity 3D. I have ran into a problem where if I pick up a weapon that was on the ground by default it does not work. My gun floats in the air. I believe the main reason for this (don't quote me on this) is that the Gun is some how not becoming a child of the camera, which is what supposed to happen. Please fix and thanks.

**This is my pick up script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUpScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public GrappleGun gunScript;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public BoxCollider coll;
    public Transform player, gunContainer, fpsCam;

    public float pickUpRange;
    public float dropForwardForce, dropUpwardForce;

    public bool equipped;
    public static bool slotFull;

    private void Start()
    {
        if(!equipped)
        {
            gunScript.enabled = false;
            rb.isKinematic = false;
            coll.isTrigger = false;
        }
        if (equipped)
        {
            gunScript.enabled = true;
            rb.isKinematic = true;
            coll.isTrigger = true;
            slotFull = true;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //equipped and e is pressed
        Vector3 distanceToPlayer = player.position - transform.position;
        if (!equipped && distanceToPlayer.magnitude <= pickUpRange && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !slotFull) PickUp();

        //Drop if equipped and q is pressed
        if (equipped && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)) Drop();
    }

    private void PickUp()
    {
        equipped = true;
        slotFull = true;

        transform.SetParent(gunContainer);
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero);
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        //Enable rb and km and coll = trigger
        rb.isKinematic = true;
        coll.isTrigger = true;

        //Enable Script
        gunScript.enabled = true;
    }

    private void Drop()
    {
        equipped = false;
        slotFull = false;

        transform.SetParent(null);

        //Enable rb and km and coll = trigger
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        coll.isTrigger = false;

        //GunCarries momentum of player
        rb.velocity = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;

        //AddForce
        rb.AddForce(fpsCam.forward * dropForwardForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        rb.AddForce(fpsCam.up * dropUpwardForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

        //Enable Script
        gunScript.enabled = false;
    }

}
```

**This is grapple hook script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GrappleGun : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer lr;
    private Vector3 grapplePoint;
    public LayerMask whatIsGrappable;
    public Transform gunTip, camera, player;
    private float maxDistance = 50f;
    private SpringJoint joint;

    void Awake()
    {
        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            StartGrapple();
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            StopGrapple();
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        DrawRope();
    }

    void StartGrapple()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(camera.position, camera.forward, out hit, maxDistance, whatIsGrappable))
        {
            grapplePoint = hit.point;
            joint = player.gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
            joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
            joint.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint;

            float distanceFromPoint = Vector3.Distance(player.position, grapplePoint);

            //the distance
            joint.maxDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.8f;
            joint.minDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.25f;


            joint.spring = 5f;
            joint.damper = 0;
            joint.massScale = 1f;

            lr.positionCount = 2;
        }
    }

    void DrawRope()
    {
        //if not grappling
        if (!joint) return;

        lr.SetPosition(0, gunTip.position);
        lr.SetPosition(1, grapplePoint);
    }

    void StopGrapple()
    {
        lr.positionCount = 0;
        Destroy(joint);
    }

    public bool IsGrappling()
    {
        return joint != null;
    }
    public Vector3 GetGrapplePoint()
    {
        return grapplePoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: @FatihAslan I don't understand what that means.

Comment: debug your code, my guess here is that your drop is also being called after you pickup, print something from these methods to be sure

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way for your situation would be to create an empty game object where you want the grappling gun to be held when it's picked up, and the empty game object parented to the camera from the scene. Then from the script, you can write these lines of code.

To reference the empty game object:
`public transform gunHoldPosition;`
And you can attach that from the scene view in Unity.
Then to make the gun snap to the position when it's held:

```
private void PickUp()
{
    equipped = true;
    slotFull = true;

    transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

    //Enable rb and km and coll = trigger
    rb.isKinematic = true;
    coll.isTrigger = true;

    //Enable Script
    gunScript.enabled = true;
}
```

Now In the Update function, you have to write a little more:

```
private void Update()
{
    //equipped and e is pressed
    Vector3 distanceToPlayer = player.position - transform.position;
    if (!equipped && distanceToPlayer.magnitude <= pickUpRange && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !slotFull) PickUp();

    //Drop if equipped and q is pressed
    if (equipped && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)) Drop();
    if (equipeed){
    /* If this script is on the gun itself, then you just have to do transform.position, but if it's on some other object then you have to reference the gun that's being picked with the variable of 'public gameObject gun;' up and say gun.transform.position*/
    transform.position = gunHoldPosition.position;
```

}
}

I'm not exactly sure why you have to do this in the Update function, but once I made a pickup script and the same thing happened to me, so I had to put the transform.postition in the Update Function. Hopefully this works for you if it doesn't reply to me and I will try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Also sorry that I am late to answer my question even though I fixed it really fast. I was making the object with the script, aka a child of the model without actually making the model a child of thing.